# Draw component in a grid cell - extjs 4

Tags: javascript, extjs4

Is it possible to include a draw component (circle or rectangle) inside a grid cell?

Thanks

Doron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Components are not generally available inside the cells as they wont participate in the layout calculation. However using a column renderer you can pretty much include any html element and hence have some leeway, but don't expect things like sorting and column moving to work properly :)

Comment: Just to complete DimitryB answer, you can try to get some inspiration here http://lucian.lature.net/extjs/demo/ActionButton/